# pandas - pd.replace and TypeError

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, replace, typeerror

I have `all_data` dataframe. I want to replace some categorical values in certain columns with numerical values. I'm trying to use this nested dictionary notation (I've checked that the brackets and curly brackets are in place, I don't think that's the issue):

```
all_data = all_data.replace({'Street': {'Pave': 1, 'Grvl': 0}},
                            {'LotShape': {'IR3': 1, 'IR2': 2, 'IR1': 3, 'Reg': 4}},
                            {'Utilities': {'ELO': 0, 'NoSeWa': 0, 'NoSewr': 0, 'AllPub': 1}},
                            {'LandSlope': {'Sev': 1, 'Mod': 2, 'Gtl': 3}},
                            {'ExterQual': {'Po': 1, 'Fa': 2, 'TA': 3, 'Gd': 4, 'Ex': 5}},
                            {'ExterCond': {'Po': 1, 'Fa': 2, 'TA': 3, 'Gd': 4, 'Ex': 5}},
                            {'BsmtQual': {'NA': 0, 'Po': 1, 'Fa': 2, 'TA': 3, 'Gd': 4,'Ex': 5}},
                            {'BsmtCond': {'NA': 0, 'Po': 1, 'Fa': 2, 'TA': 3, 'Gd': 4,'Ex': 5}},
                            {'BsmtExposure': {'NA': 0, 'No': 1, 'Mn': 2, 'Av': 3, 'Gd': 4}},
                            {'BsmtFinType1': {'NA': 0, 'Unf': 1, 'LwQ': 2, 'Rec': 3, 'BLQ': 4, 'ALQ': 5, 'GLQ': 6}},
                            {'BsmtFinType2': {'NA': 0, 'Unf': 1,'LwQ': 2,'Rec': 3, 'BLQ': 4,'ALQ': 5, 'GLQ': 6}}, 
                            {'HeatingQC': {'Po': 1,'Fa': 2,'TA': 3,'Gd': 4,'Ex': 5}},
                            {'CentralAir': {'No': 0,'Yes': 1}},
                            {'KitchenQual': {'Po': 1,'Fa': 2,'TA': 3,'Gd': 4,'Ex': 5}},
                            {'Functional': {'Sal': -7,'Sev': -6,'Maj1': -5,'Maj2': -4,'Mod': -3,'Min2': -2,'Min1': -1,
                                            'Typ': 0}},
                            {'FireplaceQu': {'NA': 0,'Po': 1,'Fa': 2,'TA': 3,'Gd': 4,'Ex': 5}},
                            {'GarageFinish': {'NA': 0,'Unf': 1,'RFn': 2, 'Fin': 3}},
                            {'GarageQual': {'NA': 0,  'Po': 1,'Fa': 2, 'TA': 3,'Gd': 4, 'Ex': 5}},
                            {'GarageCond': {'NA': 0,'Po': 1,'Fa': 2,'TA': 3,'Gd': 4,'Ex': 5}},
                            {'PavedDrive': {'N': 0,'P': 0, 'Y': 1}},
                            {'Fence': {'NA': 0, 'MnWw': 1,'GdWo': 2,'MnPrv': 3,'GdPrv': 4}},
                            {'SaleCondition': {'Abnorml': 1, 'Alloca': 1, 'AdjLand': 1, 'Family': 1, 'Normal': 0, 
                                               'Partial': 0}}
                           )
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-40-f9c9c28b7237> in <module>()
     22                             {'Fence': {'NA': 0, 'MnWw': 1,'GdWo': 2,'MnPrv': 3,'GdPrv': 4}},
     23                             {'SaleCondition': {'Abnorml': 1, 'Alloca': 1, 'AdjLand': 1, 'Family': 1, 'Normal': 0, 
---> 24                                                'Partial': 0}}
     25                            )

TypeError: replace() takes from 1 to 8 positional arguments but 23 were given
```

If I remove the 'SaleCondition' row from the above code, the error is again there but this time referring to 'Fence', and so on, for each line of code from bottom up. I've googled but have no idea what this means. Help MUCH appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do something like :

```
df.replace({'Fence':{'NA': 0, 'MnWw': 1,'GdWo': 2,'MnPrv': 3,'GdPrv': 4},'SaleCondition':{'Abnorml': 1, 'Alloca': 1, 'AdjLand': 1, 'Family': 1, 'Normal': 0,
                                               'Partial': 0}})
```

the format should be `.replace({'col1':{},'col2':{}})` ***not*** `.replace({'col1':{}},{'col2':{}})`

Comment: @P.Prunesquallor Yw~ have a nice day

Comment: @P.Prunesquallor I notice I answered one of your question this morning LOL

Comment: You're my savior :D